# mysql: join on with or condition displaying result twice

Tags: mysql, sql, database

why this query displaying same result twice.

```
"SELECT * from sony.bsha 
inner join sony.frndreq 
on sony.frndreq.from='"+email+"' or sony.frndreq.to='"+email+"'";
```

And please tell to me how to stop displaying data twice.

Comment: Can you put up sqlfiddle?

Comment: Why are you using parameters in an "ON" clause here? Usually, you join "bsha JOIN frndreq ON bsha.field = frndreq.field WHERE frndreq.from = ... OR frndreq.to = ..."

Comment: Please let us know if any of these helped you. If not, please provide more information, eg. table schemas.

Comment: Sorry i don't have more knowledge on it see my complete question at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138798/retrive-two-table-values-on-checking-first-table-values-and-then-searching-for-s)

Answer (score 1):

You should join your tables on some common field, and then use `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sony.bsha 
INNER JOIN sony.frndreq 
ON sony.bsha.someField = sony.frndreq.someField
WHERE sony.frndreq.from='"+email+"' OR sony.frndreq.to='"+email+"' "
```

If you're still getting double results use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`. It's hard to say anything more not being given your database schema etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
"SELECT * 
 from sony.bsha 
      inner join sony.frndreq 
          on sony.frndreq.from='"+email+"' or sony.frndreq.to='"+email+"'
GROUP BY sony.frndreq.from
    ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to specify a condition on a common field between two tables. Then only you will get unique records.

```
"SELECT * FROM sony.bsha 
INNER JOIN sony.frndreq ON sony.bsha.id = sony.frndreq.bid 
WHERE sony.frndreq.from='"+email+"' OR sony.frndreq.to='"+email+"'";
```

In above SQL I assumed fields for

```
sony.bsha.id = sony.frndreq.bid
```

condition where `sony.bsha.id` is `Primary Key` in `Left Table` and `sony.frndreq.bid` is `Foriegn Key` in `Right Table`.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that even though you are using an inner join that it will still return more than one of the "same" record if redundant data exists. Perhaps if you check "email" you may find more than one occurrence of a value in which you are getting duplicates for. Run a query using a value from the duplicate records you are getting and see what you get.

In the case there are duplicate values for email (and that is not in error), do as the other user has said and use DISTINCT or GROUP BY. Remember though for those to work that all the fields you specify in the select must be the same, not just email.